# Extend C Drive with .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a .bat file at first startup of Windows which will extend the primary hard drive space ( C: ) with all unallocated disk space.

I can do it manually using

```
diskpart
select volume 1
extend
```

However when I put that in a .bat file and run it does nothing.

This is for Windows 2008 R2

Comment: Try using a diskpart script `diskpart /s ScriptName.ext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of this. But perhaps you could try this.

Create a .txt file with name as Command.txt. [or whatever name you like]
Input the following using notepad.

```
select volume 1
extend
```

Now create a .bat file and store it in the same location as where you have stored Command.txt

This batch file should contain the following code

```
diskpart.exe /s Command.txt
exit
```

Now run the batch file.

Please forgive me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: You should probably give it an `exit` as last line to terminate `diskpart`

Comment: I just edited it. Thanks @Stephan . However to the best of my knowledge, the script terminates even if there is no exit command attached. Correct me if I am wrong. Anyway, it is always desirable to terminate a program through the code itself. So Thanks again.

Comment: didn't try, because I need my data... `:D`

Comment: what about trying on a VM?, Anyway the answer is accepted - and think it may work.

Answer (score 0):

try make .bat file and put this code

```
echo select disk 0 > Command.txt
echo select volume 1 >> Command.txt
echo extend >> Command.txt
diskpart.exe /s Command.txt
pause
```